# Validating multiple inputs field with Yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I'm currently using Formik and validating with Yup.

I am looking to validate 2 dates, a start date, and an end date.

This was quite simple at first, I had two input fields, `start_date` and `end_date`. Both of these were just text inputs which accepted the following format, `MM-YYYY`. The validation is good enough, it first turns that string into a date, using `moment(value, "MM-YYYY")`.

From this, we then had the following tests:

```
start_date: Yup.string()
.test(
    'test1',
    'Format must be MM-YYYY',
    function (value){
        return moment(value, "MM-YYYY", true).isValid()
    }
)
.test(
    'test2',
    'Start date must be before end date',
    function(value){
        let { end_date } = this.parent;
        return moment(value, "MM-YYYY").isBefore(moment(end_date, "MM-YYYY"))
    }
)
```

`test1` simply checks that the `MM-YYYY` is a valid date. `test2` checks that the `start_date` is before the `end_date`. For the sake of simplicity, the `end_date` tests are the same, except there is any extra test. The extra test checks that the `end_date` is equal to or less than the current date.

That is what I currently have, however what I want is 4 input boxes:

- `start_date_month` (01, 02, 03...)
- `start_date_year` (2000, 2001...)
- `end_date_month`
- `end_date_year`

This is easy to do, but the tests will work a bit different, I'm not sure if we can test `start_date_month` and `start_date_year` together. In essence I need to concatinate them with `-` to create `MM-YYYY` again.

Any ideas how to do this with Yup?

Answer (score 1):

Very short lived problem. It seems you can just pass in other inputs like: `let {start_date_year} = this.parent` in the `start_date_month` test.